# Access 'using' directive from different files

Tags: c#

Consider the next solution structure:

**File 1:**

```
using MyClass = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;

namespace NamespaceA
{
    class  A
    {
        MyClass a;
    }
}

namespace NamespaceB
{
    class B
    {
        MyClass b;
    }
}
```

**File 2:**

```
namespace NamespaceC
{
    class C
    {
        MyClass c; // <-- The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found 
    }
}
```

How can I access to `MyClass` definition from File2? I tried to move it into `NamespaceA` and use `using MyClass = NamespaceA.MyClass` in File2, but had no success.
My goal is to define complicate type in one place, not in all files where it is used.

Comment: It's an alias for that type in the current file, not everywhere else. Consider the mess if that was allowed

Comment: Seems like you're utilizing aliases when you should either be directly utilizing the type or making subclasses (if you need additional logic).

Comment: "My goal is to define complicate type in one place, not in all files where it is used." That sounds like you should define those types in some namespace, and reference _that namespace_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a "using alias directive."

[Per MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

> The scope of a `using` directive is limited to the file in which it appears.

There's no way do what you're trying to do; you'll have to add the alias to each file in which you wish to use it.

Comment: Yes, it was my inattention. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the using to each file you wish to use it in...

**File2:**

```
using MyClass = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;

namespace NamespaceC
{
    class C
    {
        MyClass c; // Should work now.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 10 and later, you can use a global using directive:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier